# How can one use an instance method as decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How the following code works, without passing the function (func) to the object method task().

```
class Pipeline:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tasks = list()
        
    def task(self):
        def inner(func):
            self.tasks.append(func)
            return func
        return inner

pipeline = Pipeline()
    
@pipeline.task()
def first_task(x):
    return x + 1

print(pipeline.tasks)
```

For example, comparing it to the following. Adding additional functionality to a given function. I just can't figure out in the above example how the func is getting passed to task() method.

```
def logger(func):
    def inner(*args):
        print('Calling function: {}'.format(func.__name__))
        print('With args: {}'.format(args))
        return func(*args)
    return inner

@logger
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Comment: You are passing a function. The function defined with `def first_task(x)` is the one passed as `func`. That is what decorators do.

Comment: Why the following give me the error? self: pipeline then how is first_task passed as function without passing it as an argument to the task method. `def task(self, func):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```py
@pipeline.task()
def first_task(x):
    return x + 1
```

`pipeline.task()` calls the `task` method of `pipeline`. This returns the function `inner`.

The `@` indicates that this function (`inner`) is to be used as a decorator. So `inner` is called and the subsequent function definition `def first_task...` is passed as its argument, `func`.

`inner` adds the function `func` to the pipeline's list of tasks.

You can read it as something like:

```py
inner = pipeline.task()
# inner is a function created by pipeline.task()
#  to add a function to the pipeline's task list
@inner
def first_task(x):
    return x + 1
```

And decorator syntax makes this behave similarly to:

```py
inner = pipeline.task()
def first_task(x):
    return x + 1
first_task = inner(first_task)
```